# Gradle Plugin - getArtifacts() Results in 'Could Not resolve all dependencies for configuration...'

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin, android-sdk-2.3

I am trying to write a gradle task (code below) that aggregates information from the `ResolvedArtifact` objects within a multi-project build. However, when I run the task on a sample android project (https://github.com/gmetal/sample-dependency-check-app) using gradle 4.8.1 I get the following error:

```
07:29 $ gradle clean resolveArtifacts
> Task :app:resolveArtifacts FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:resolveArtifacts'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugAndroidTestCompileClasspath'.
   > More than one variant of project :mylibrary matches the consumer attributes:
       - Configuration ':mylibrary:debugApiElements' variant android-aidl:
           - Found artifactType 'android-aidl' but wasn't required.
           - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found compatible value 'debug'.
           - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
           - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
           - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-api' and found compatible value 'java-api'.
       - Configuration ':mylibrary:debugApiElements' variant android-classes:
           - Found artifactType 'android-classes' but wasn't required.
           - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found compatible value 'debug'.
           - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
           - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
           - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-api' and found compatible value 'java-api'.
       - Configuration ':mylibrary:debugApiElements' variant android-manifest:
           - Found artifactType 'android-manifest' but wasn't required.
           - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found compatible value 'debug'.
           - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
           - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
           - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-api' and found compatible value 'java-api'.
       - Configuration ':mylibrary:debugApiElements' variant android-renderscript:
           - Found artifactType 'android-renderscript' but wasn't required.
           - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found compatible value 'debug'.
           - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
           - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
           - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-api' and found compatible value 'java-api'.
       - Configuration ':mylibrary:debugApiElements' variant jar:
           - Found artifactType 'jar' but wasn't required.
           - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found compatible value 'debug'.
           - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
           - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
           - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-api' and found compatible value 'java-api'.
```

The code for the resolveArtifacts task is below:

```
import org.gradle.api.DefaultTask
import org.gradle.api.Project
import org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration
import org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolvedArtifact
import org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskAction

import static org.gradle.api.specs.Specs.SATISFIES_ALL

class ResolveArtifacts extends DefaultTask {
    ResolveArtifacts() {
        group = 'Sample Task'
        description = 'Attempts to resolve artifacts.'
    }

    @TaskAction
    analyze() {
        project.allprojects.collectMany { Project currentProject ->
            currentProject.configurations.findAll {
                canBeResolved(it)
            }.each { Configuration configuration ->
                configuration.resolvedConfiguration.lenientConfiguration.getArtifacts(SATISFIES_ALL).each { ResolvedArtifact artifact ->
                    logger.lifecycle("------ resolved ${artifact}")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    def canBeResolved(configuration) {
        configuration.metaClass.respondsTo(configuration, "isCanBeResolved") ?
                configuration.isCanBeResolved() : true
    }
}
```

Any suggestions for how one can resolve the above error?  The original issue was posted to the [dependency-check-gradle](https://github.com/jeremylong/dependency-check-gradle/issues/71) on github.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to use the configuration.incoming.artifactView and filter for just the artifact types that are needed:

```
def artifactType = Attribute.of('artifactType', String)
def types = ['jar', 'aar']
types.each { type ->
    configuration.incoming.artifactView {
        attributes {
            it.attribute(artifactType, type)
        }
    }.artifacts.each {
        println "artifact file: ${it.file}"
    }
}
```

See my [github issue](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/5953#issuecomment-405209713) with the gradle team.